# Kibana + Elasticsearch without Logstash possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am kind of new to Logstash. We have a legacy web application which ships logs directly to **Redis** server in JSON format. Now I want to display that logs on web interface.
 What I read about **Elasticsearch** and **Kibana**, I am really impressed by their functionalities.
Is that possible to feed logs from redis to directly elasticsearch and then visualized them using Kibana ?

Comment: You can view any index of elasticsearch in kibana, logstash is just creating another index in elasticsearch so kibana can view it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Kibana can display any information stored in ElasticSearch indexes.

You'll need a way of automatically indexing items from Redis to ElasticSearch though. You can rather write your own script (should be pretty simple in your case) or use existing software like [Redis plugin for LogStash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/redis) or [Redis river plugin for ElasticSearch](https://github.com/sksamuel/elasticsearch-river-redis) (deprecated)

Comment: Hi @Eugene, if I use **Redis plugin for LogStash** then I will have to setup LogStash. Am I correct ? I want to bypass LogStash because my logs are already on Redis, that too in JSON format. Using LogStash will unnecessarily increase overhead. Right ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Setting up logstash is not a overhead, writing your plugin for Redis could be. For your problem, you can do one thing, though its a bit painful. If you can export your data as json formatted text file, you can import the file to elasticsearch using a simple logstash command. If data is quite big, then you have to write your own logstash script to 'plumb' data from redis to elastic. Writing plumbing script in logstash would be easier in logstash than in elastic, i guess.

Comment: @BhushanPatil, the only way to avoid the overhead is to make your application save logs directly to ElasticSearch instead of (or in addition to) Redis. Now, LogStash should not be too much overhead if you configure it correctly. Just try it and see if it slows down your system. I personally prefer custom importer scripts because then I can fine-tune the fields, the mappings, I can do various value conversions before saving, I can reindex stuff later if something goes wrong, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, you can use Kibana to browse non-logstash indices just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another connectors like mongodb and to insert data into elasticsearch or directly insert data kibana is independent of logstash,logstash is mainly used for processing logs data which you can do the way u like.